# Are all abelian subgroups of a dihedral group cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

Are all abelian subgroups of a dihedral group cyclic?

Attempt: I have counter-examples for n=1,2 so I know that it isn't true for n<3. Is it true for n≥3? How do you know this?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I'm with Ben. There are not so many subgroups of the dihedral group to consider and if you understand what those are you will be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

For $n$ equal to a multiple of $4$, $n=4k$ with $k \ge 1$, the Dihedral group $D_n$ contains a copy of the non-cyclic abelian group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

One can see this geometrically. Picture a regular $4k$-sided polygon $P$, centered at the origin of the plane, having one opposite pair of sides parallel to the $x$-axis, and another opposite pair of sides parallel to the $y$-axis. The symmetry group of $P$ is $D_{4k}$, and it consists of rotations about the origin through angles which are multiples of $2\pi/4k$ plus reflections across lines that bisect opposite side pairs or that connect opposite vertex pairs. Both the $x$ and $y$-axes bisect opposite side pairs, so reflections across those two axes are in the symmetry group, and they generate a subgroup isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G\le D_{2n}$ be a subgroup and $H\le G$ the subgroup of rotations in $G$. As $H\le C_n<D_{2n}$ because the subgroup $C_n$ comprises all rotations in $D_{2n}$, we know $H$ is cyclic, so assume $H<G$ is proper.

(I am using $D_{2n}$ to denote the dihedral group of order $2n$.)

Rotations preserve orientation and reflections reverse them, so composing two reflections yields a rotation and composing one of each yields a reflection. Pick any reflection $g\in G\setminus H$. Then multiplying by $g$ is a bijection $H\leftrightarrow G\setminus H$ so $[G:H]=2$. As $H$ is cyclic, write $H=\langle h\rangle$. Then $G=\langle g,h\rangle$ is *also* a dihedral group $D_{2m}$ where $m=|h|$. If $G$ is abelian, then $G$ must be the Klein four group as that is the only abelian dihedral group, and $g$ must have order $2$ in $C_n$.

If $n$ is odd then $D_{2n}$ has no noncyclic abelian subgroups, but if $n$ is even then $D_{2n}$ has a copy of the Klein four group $C_2\times C_2$ generated by the unique $180^\circ$ rotation and any flip.

Comment: How do I prove the last part? (if n is odd)

Comment: @tmac_balla If $F$ is any flip and $R$ is any rotation, we have $FRF^{-1}=R^{-1}$. In order for a subgroup containing $F$ and $R$ to be abelian, that means the $R$ must equal its inverse. Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

There are two notations a dihedral group and $n\in\mathbb{N}$? Some use the notation $D_n=<r,s\,|\,s^2=r^n=1,\,rs=sr^{-1}>$ whereas others use the notation $D_{2n}=<r,s\,|\,s^2=r^n=1,\,rs=sr^{-1}>$. I'll use the second one (the group itself doesn't change).

I wonder what are your counter-examples. For $n=1$, we have $|D_2|=2$ thus $D_2\cong Z_2$ where $Z_2$ is the cyclic group of order $2$. Thus $D_2$ is cyclic and any subgroup of $D_2$ is either $1$ or $D_2$. In both cases, we get a cyclic abelian subgroup. But for $n=2$, you're right because $D_4\cong V_4$ the Klein $4$-group thus $D_4$ is abelian but not cyclic.

Now for $n\ge 3$, I will give you a hint: if $n$ is even prove that $Z(D_{2n})=<r^\frac{n}{2}>$ is the center of $D_{2n}$. Think about the reflexion $s$. Like that you'll be able to make a counter-example (a non cyclic subgroup must contain $s$ and a rotation). The statement is therefore false for even $n$. Now if $n$ is odd prove that $Z(D_{2n})=1$. As we said, a non-cyclic subgroup of $D_{2n}$ must have $s$ and a rotation (a power of $r$). Would such a group be abelian? You can prove that it isn't the case. Thus all abelian subgroups of $D_{2n}$ for odd $n$ are cyclic.