# Systematically finding nonnormal covering of Klein bottle by torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I understand that this topic have been discussed again and again, yet I'm posting this question because I haven't find an satisfying answer. Most answer didn't show how they construct the covering. So I'm posting this question again, and sharing my progresss. I couldn't finish it. Any correction or advice or hint is welcome.

My approach for this problem is something like that: Notice that $H:=\langle a,b\mid bab^{-1}a\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$, from which there is a epimorphism to $D_n$. Fundamental group of torus is abelian, so we are looing for an abelian nonnormal subgroup of $H$, whose image is an abelian nonnormal subgroup of $D_n$. Also notice that all covering by torus factors through the classical double cover, so we'd better consider $D_{n}$ with $n$ even.

Now there's a classification theorem for $D_n$'s subgroup: $\langle a^d \rangle$ with $d\vert n$, which is always normal, and $\langle a^d, a^rb\rangle$, where $d\vert n$ and $0\leq r <d$. When $n$ is even,  $\langle a^2,b\rangle$ and $\langle a^2,ab\rangle$ are also normal, and that's all normal subgroups. (See [This article](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral2.pdf)).

Now back to our question. Notice that $D_2$ and $D_4$ are themselves abelian(hence has no nonnormal subgroup), so we'd better start at $D_6$. (This is the reason why a nonnormal covering of torus has at least 6 sheets). We already know what does a nonnormal subgroup looks like, we want to find an abelian subgroup. [The answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1441547/492146) shows the only noncyclic abelian subgroup is $D_2\cong V_4$, the Klein four group. So the subgroup should be $\langle a^3,b \rangle$.

Then we consider the pullback in $H$, and that's where I got stucked. It looks the pullback is just the covering by Klein bottle.

Where did I go wrong?

(Something might help for those not familiar with Klein bottle: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/6481/492146) explains why the finite covering space must be tori or Klein bottles.)

**Update**

I realized something must go wrong in my argument. An answer to this question is a six sheeted cover $\langle a^3, a^2b^2\rangle$, and the image in $D_6$ is, since $b^2=e$, $\langle a^3\rangle$. It is a normal subgroup of $D_6$.

I have no ideal what's going on...

**Update on 9/19**

I asked my professor and he said even if we had an abelian subgroup of $D_n$ , because $D_n$ does not act properly (sorry I can't recall the exact word) on $\ker\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}\to D_n$ its preimage might not be abelian. So no, this approach does not work.

Some other reference: Notice that $a\mapsto a^k$ gives a monomorphism, and when $k>2$ the image is not normal ( For $a^2 b a b^{-1}= a$ gives ​$a^2b=aba^{-1}$, and when $k>2$ $ab^2$ is not contained in the image). This is, at least part of, the systematical way of finding nonnormal covering of Klein bottle by Klein bottles. (The idea is given [here](https://mastodon.sbpk.fr/@wsb/106937443586921752) in Chinese.)

I'll try to read materials of infinite groups and see if and I can find a satisfying answer; for now I don't think I can make any progress. Still, any hints/answers/references are welcomed.